# Show that $1^3+2^3+....+n^3=(1+2+3+...+n)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

> Block quote

I use induction 
N=1
And n=k
But in case of n=k+1 i can't write the thing .help

> Block quote

Comment: The proof becomes easier if you use the formulas for $1+2+3+\cdots+n$ and $1+2^3+3^3+\cdots +n^3$ and prove them via induction.

Comment: Explain please I can't get answer

Comment: You can have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Nicomachus_theorem_3D.svg

Comment: The formula for $$S(n)=1+2+3+\cdots +n$$ can easily be found (even without induction) : You can write the sum in reverse $$S(n)=n+\cdots+3+2+1$$ and immediately see that $$2S(n)=n\cdot(n+1)$$ Now show by induction that $$1+2^3+3^3+\cdots +n^3=S(n)^2$$ holds for all $n$.

Comment: @Peter thanks ..Nice approach sir

Comment: @Peter One can discuss whether that's without induction. Sure, there is no explicit induction with a base case and an induction step, but something is happening inside those $\cdots$, and it is very induction-like.

Comment: I agree in the case of $1+2^3+\cdots +n^3$ (I would not have an idea to show it without induction) , but the above sum-method does not use induction at all. We have $n$ columns with sum $n+1$, where is induction involved in this approach ?

Comment: @Peter There are many places induction can hide in an argument like that. For one thing, addition, multiplication and the natural numbers themselves are technically _defined_ using induction so you can't use them without inducing somewhere. But even without that, you have things like showing that all the columns indeed do sum to $n+1$, that there are $n$ of them and that $(n+1) + (n+1) + \cdots + (n+1) = n(n+1)$ all look suspiciously like they have induction hidden deep, deep down. "Without induction" is a really hairy claim if you get pedantic.

Comment: @Arthur I agree that it is pedantic. I do not think that the intent of the question is to apply a formal proof that addition and multiplication works (and to show THIS with induction). And if we accept that they do, no induction whatsoever remains. But since we need induction for the other part, this discussion is meaningless anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  Expand the right side as $((1+2+3+\ldots+n)+(n+1))^2$  The square of the first term is the sum of the cubes up to $n$ by the induction hypothesis.  The cross term is $2(n+1)\frac 12n(n+1)$